# Postsharp - App Settings configuration check

Tags: c#, postsharp

I've created a PostSharp aspect to throw compilation error when key in app.config file not exists, but ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.HasKeys() returns "false" when i check it in CompileTimeValidate method. Can help me? Thanks!

```
[Serializable]
public class ConfigurationValueRequiredAttribute : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    // Method invoked at build time. It validates that the aspect has been applied to an acceptable method.
    public override bool CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method)
    {
        bool valid = true;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Test"]))
        {

            Message.Write(SeverityType.Error, "CUSTOM02", "Test not exists!");
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you check for any keys? I don't think that the app.config will load on compile time. You could try load the app.config manually or load the app.config as XML and do some xpath for checking that the keys exists.

Answer (score 2):

PostSharp compile-time checking is its own separate process. It's not running within the context of your application and doesn't load or read your app.config.

To confirm, I used your attribute in a test class and got the error message, "Test not exists!"

Then I added this to
C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.2.29\bin.Release\postsharp-net40-x86-srv.exe.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="test" value="123"/>
</appSettings>
```

...built again, and the error went away. That's the .config file it's reading.